# Огромный SQL-файл c апдейтами

Tags: python, mysql

Дано:

- БД с таблицей в 60 тысяч записей (MySQL).
- MySQL крутится под XAMPP (MacOS).
- SQL-файл c 20 тысячами SQL-запросами (UPDATE) по одному в каждой строке.
- Запросы вариативные: иногда просто перенос из колонки в колонку, иногда с делением на несколько колонок, иногда с корректурой текста.
- Текстовые поля неиндексированные.

Примеры запросов (*отформатировал для того, чтобы читалось легче)*:

```
UPDATE tab1 
   SET foo = '', 
       bar = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 
       baz = 'Consectetur adipisicing elit' 
 WHERE foo LIKE 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...';
```

Нужно каким-либо образом эти самые запросы выполнить.

Сначала я хотел импортировать файл через PhpMyAdmin. [Процесс умирает по таймауту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/), поэтому импорт через PhpMyAdmin - не вариант.

Накатал на коленке питоновский скрипт (который - в отличие от PHP - не умирает по временному ограничению) и прошелся по SQL-файлу построчно, выполняя запросы один за другим.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pswd', host='127.0.0.1', database='db')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

file = open('defs_update.sql', encoding='utf-8')

for line in file:
    cursor.execute(line)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
file.close
```

Все обновилось. Задача решена, однако вопрос времени меня смущает очень сильно. Предположим, речь шла бы не о соотношении 20k к 60k, а о соотношении 300m к 900m - я боюсь даже представить сколько времени для этого потребуется, если здесь понадобилось около 40 минут.

Есть ли способы выполнить множественные запросы из файла быстрее?

**UPD (в комментарии не помещается). К сути вопроса отношения не имеет, поскольку выгоды по времени нет.**

При запуске через терминал командой

```
mysql -p db < updates.sql
```

ничего не произошло. Логи не ведутся, поэтому показать нечего. Однако если выполнить в [MySQL Query Browser](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,270752,270752) команду

```
source updates.sql
```

в терминал начинает выводится простыня вот таких сообщений:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,20 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

При выполнении ровно тех же команд через PhpMyAdmin вижу, что строки обновлены:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET ... # Затронуто строк: 1.
```

Comment: Может какие-то фокусы с пользователем, его схемой базы  и т.п. ?

Answer (score 6):

простите, даже боюсь поинтересоваться: а зачем выполнять sql построчно? Одним разом почему бы и не? Что-то вроде mysql -u user -ppassword db < dump.sql

Comment: Сделал так. Минут сорок в терминале ничего не происходило, при том что СУБД что-то делала (судя по усилившемуся шуму из системника). А в итоге - ничего не изменилось. И никаких алертов/варнингов не вывалилось.

Скормил тот же файл Питону - запросы выполнились. 

P.S. Поскольку  в файле очень много запросов на обновление текстовых неиндексированных полей, говорить о выполнении одним разом - не совсем корректно. В любом случае каждый последующий запрос не будет выполняться раньше, чем будет отработан предыдущий. Python ли, обращение ли к MySQL из терминала - по времени одинаково.

Comment: простите, очень хочется это увидеть

Comment: Мне и самому этот вариант кажется самым очевидным. И очень хочется знать, что пошло не так. Однако - ни алертов, ни изменений.

Comment: не может быть, чтобы совсем молчание. А в логах что?

Comment: Елена, увы, это так. А чтоб добавить драматизма - логирование выключено.

Comment: Может просто к моменту запуска изменения уже были сделаны Вашей другой программой?

Вот ничего нового и не видно...

Comment: @avp, нет.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, возможно Вы уже читали [Increasing performance of bulk updates of large tables in MySQL](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2013/11/06/increasing-performance-of-bulk-updates-of-large-tables-in-mysql/).

Если нет, посмотрите. Мне кажется, там есть здравые мысли.

--

Вообще же, следует понимать, что (при всех неубиваемых плюсах) любая СУБД штука не слишком шустрая.

Answer (score 1):

В PhpMyadmin есть галочка "Разрешить скрипту разбивать процесс импорта при приближении временного лимита. (Может быть использовано при импорте файлов большого размера, однако при этом вероятны проблемы с транзакциями.)"

По сути вопроса про питон: объедини запросы в транзакцию и коммить её каждую тысячу строк.

Comment: не нужно разбивать на пачки по тысячу запросов. Просто в самом начале открыть транзакцию (выполнить запрос "BEGIN;") а в самом конце - закрыть ("COMMIT"). Скорость увеличиться в сотни раз.

Можно и в сам файл добавить.

Comment: Мне кажется все зависит от рода данных в этом файле. большие транзакции могут нехило скушать памяти на сервере.

Comment: Это не радостно - разбивать процесс импорта. В итоге приходится следить за процессом, ожидая, пока он отвалится, чтобы вновь загрузить файл. Собственно, этот процесс меня сильно напряг и я обратился к Питону.

Comment: @eri, @KoVadim, begin/commit не дали никакого выигрыша по времени. Сильно подозреваю, что в данном случае имеет смысл оптимизировать саму базу данных.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, вероятно нужно еще `SET autocommit=0`...  
Ну и вообще про [Bulk Data Loading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) почитать. Там множество нюансов, как можно ускорить. И выгрузка может/должна быть определенная и загрузка при определенных настройках, зависит от сервера и т.д.